# Naviswork FBX model is far away frome center

Tags: import, .fbx, origin

i am working on some AutoCad Naviswork models. These models were exported as FBX, as soon as I import them in blender i think they keep the original location of Naviswork so they are really far away from my view. I have tried:

1. Clearing the location
2. Set origin geomtry to origin

however the model in both options as its composed by different object gets really messed up and disorganized.
Anyone knows how to bring this model to the center without affecting the shape? I have tried several options but just those two brings the model to the center, other options makes the object just dissapear and you some

Comment: could you please share a blend file with your objects before trying to fix the problem?